# Selenium test execute

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Hi in Pycharm I have installed Selenium in virtualenv. I try execute

```
from selenium import webdriver
#from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

#binary = FirefoxBinary('/webdriver/firefox')
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://localhost:8000')

assert 'Django ' in browser.title
```

but I have error

> (django_env)darek@Toshiba:~/PycharmProjects/Django$ python
>   functional_tests.py  Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "functional_tests.py", line 5, in 
>       browser = webdriver.Firefox()   File "/home/darek/.virtualenvs/django_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py",
>   line 140, in **init**
>       self.service.start()   File "/home/darek/.virtualenvs/django_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
>   line 74, in start
>       stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in **init**
>       restore_signals, start_new_session)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
>       raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg) NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory Exception ignored in: > Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/darek/.virtualenvs/django_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
>   line 173, in **del**
>       self.stop()   File "/home/darek/.virtualenvs/django_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
>   line 145, in stop
>       if self.process is None: AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'

I download geckodriver ver. 11 and add to variable path and add in bashrc

> export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/bin export
>   WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/MyProject
>   export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3 source
>   /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
>
> source django_env/bin/activate export
>   PATH=$PATH:/home/darek/webdriver/firefox/geckodriver export
>   PATH=$PATH:/home/darek/webdriver/firefox/wires

what can I do more?

Comment: I add that in Linux terminal it is ok but in Pycharm terminal is not.

Comment: this should be fixed in the latest selenium